# SQL Server 2005: Aligning indexes with partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, partitioning

I'm attempting to align an index with a partitioned table, but the partition key column is nullable in the table definition.

In order to align the indexes I have to make this field not null, but when I attempt to alter the column on the table I receive an error saying that the table depends on that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the partition scheme from that table, correct the data issue, then repartition.

Or, create a new, properly partitioned version of the table with the right constraints and put your data into it from the old table.

Comment: To remove the partition scheme I just need to drop the clustered index and then re-create the clustered index off the partition scheme such as CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX BLAH ON [TABLE] (FIELD) ON PRIMARY?

Comment: You will also need to drop the function and scheme after that.  There's a walkthrough here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/john_daskalakis/archive/2009/02/06/9401925.aspx